# Is it possible to change font color for only a part of the string in card power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dax expression where I am concatenating strings with other dax measures

```
Net WP = 
    "Net Written Premium " 
    & FORMAT([CY YTD],"$#,##,,.0M") 
    & " vs. " & FORMAT([PY YTD],"$#,##,,.0M") 
    & " " & MAX(dim_Date[Year]) -1 
    & " "& [Net Wr Premium YOY Title]
```

Result look like this:

[image]

Is any way I can change the font color for only the last part of the string? ([Net Wr Premium YOY Title])

**so it should look like this:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Maybe there are special visuals for that that I am not aware of?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can apply conditional formatting to almost any visual now, you can find it in a "hidded" menu, but what you ask is not possible, the whole string will be colored.
Have a look at the custom visuals in the marketplace, maybe you will find something that helps you.

For the conditional formatting of the card visual:
Formatting -> Data label -> Color (hover it, and 3 dots will appear on the right, there you will find the conditional formatting)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat your way around this by using two cards  Put the conditional formatting on one card, turn off all the borders and labels, and set it to just the measure.  Then put it right on top of the other card that has your desired text.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]